# Visa to Finland

Tags: visas, transit, us-citizens, finland

I am a US citizen and have a long connection (23 hours)in Helsinki on my way back to New York from Paris. Do I need a visa? Can I leave the airport and stay overnight in Helsinki?

Comment: As jpatokal mentioned, you don't need a visa. The flight from Paris to Helsinki will essentially be like a domestic flight - you won't go through border control in Paris on departure or Helsinki on arrival. It is on the following day when you are departing from Helsinki for New York that you will exit the Schengen area.

Answer (score 1):

As a US citizen, **you do not need a visa to visit Finland**, or anywhere else in the Schengen area for that matter, so you're welcome to leave the airport and stay overnight in Helsinki.

From the Finnish Ministry of Foreign Affairs:
https://um.fi/documents/-/asset_publisher/caSu4obBG5lW/content/yhdysvallat-matkustusasiakirjat-suomeen/385107?p_p_auth=TjAOgnNm&curAsset=0&stId=47307